# Unable to change a variable in running python program

Tags: python

I have a program running on several threads and I'm trying to change a variable `self.pausing`, through the telegram api, while the program is running. I made a function that changes the variable upon receiving a message:

```py
from time import sleep
import threading

class program:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.pausing = False
        
    def paus(self):
        if self.pausing == False:
            self.pausing = True
            print('self.pausing = True')
        elif self.pausing == True:
            self.pausing = False
            print('self.pausing = False')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.pausing == False:
                sleep(2)
                print(self.pausing)
                sleep(2)
                print('Doing things...')
            elif self.pausing == True:
                print('Pausing..')
                sleep(2)
        
    def main(self):
        threading.Thread(target=telegram().main).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.run).start()



class telegram:
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
     
    def main(self):
        while True:
            sleep(8)
            print('A message was recieved!')
            program().paus()
```

When a message is received  the function is run and prints successfully, but the variable `self.pausing` isn't changed.

I guess I'm misunderstanding something about self.* variables. My expected output would be the variable to be changed.

Comment: This code is ok, but means nothing out of context. It is more likely that `paus` is not called at all. You'll need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'll try to write something that reproduces the error. But if the text is printed, the function is ran, or?

Comment: Where is the `paus` function?  I'm guessing inside a class, but can you show the class too so we can understand?  And the code running the function?

Comment: I updated the my answer with a code that reproduces the problem. without the real telegram class off course, but the principle is the same

Comment: What is `program().change()` supposed to do? This is creating a new instance of `program`, calling change() on it, then discarding the instance; is that what you want? If that’s where your supposed self.var is supposed to change, you should probably be passing the single instance of `program` as a parameter to the Telegram instance. But as your code isn’t a [mre] no-one can run it to try this out. Make the code a [mre] that shows the problem you’re having, using your dummy Telegram class.

Comment: It's supposed to change the variable `self.pausing` in the `program class` . I'll make a telegram class that acts like it would receive a message

Comment: I updated my question with a reproducible example. The goal would be for `program()` to instead start printing `True` and `Pausing...`  when the first message is received.

Comment: In `telegram.main()` you create a _new_ instance of `program` every time. That new instance initializes itself with `self.pausing = False`every time.. What you should do instead: You need to keep the instance of `program` which is running `program.main()` in a variable. Then you can call `paus()` on that same instance every time.

Comment: so just make the contents of telegram class a part of program class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You span multiple instances of your classes you need to just spawn one of each.

Here is the working code that you can run:

```
from time import sleep
import threading

class program:
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.pausing = False
        
    def paus(self):
        if self.pausing == False:
            self.pausing = True
            print('self.pausing = True')
        elif self.pausing == True:
            self.pausing = False
            print('self.pausing = False')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.pausing == False:
                sleep(2)
                print(self.pausing)
                sleep(2)
                print('Doing things...')
            elif self.pausing == True:
                print('Pausing..')
                sleep(2)
        
    def main(self):
        prog = self
        tel = telegram(prog)
        threading.Thread(target=tel.main).start()
        threading.Thread(target=prog.run).start()



class telegram:
    
    def __init__(self, prog):
        self.prog = prog
     
    def main(self):
        while True:
            sleep(2)
            print('A message was recieved!')
            self.prog.paus()


p = program()
p.main()
```

Comment: I moved the contents of `telegram` class into `program` which also worked. However this is definitely more practical, thanks!